# Using php to display data on web

Tags: php, html, css, database

I'm developing a question and answer app and the answers are stored in a database(phpmyadmin). The data looks good in the database, but when displayed on the web it displays one giant paragraph. Have tried nl2br(), white-space:pre-wrap, explode but none seem to work. Check out the code below.

user.php is the ui where the question is and the submit button which pops up the answer.

```
 <?php
    @include 'includes/connect.php';
    
    if (isset($_GET['answer'])) {
        $answer = $_GET['answer'];
        $delete = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM 'q_form' WHERE 'answer'= $answer");
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>UI</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <?php
    
        ?>
        <div class="question">
            <p><strong>Question One (a)</strong> </p>
            <p>
                (a) Circumstances under which impairment tests on exploration and evaluation of assets are
                required</p>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" id="submit">Answer</button>
    
            </form>
            <?php
    
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM q_form;
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        foreach (explode(',', $row['answer']) as $ans) {
                            echo htmlspecialchars($ans);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>     
        

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

signup.inc.php(connects with the input page)
signup.inc.php is the code that provides the
instructions for the input to be stored in
he database.

```
<?php

@include_once 'connect.php'; 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   
    $question = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['question']);
    $answer = mysqli_escape_string ($conn, $_POST['answer']); 
    $insert = "INSERT INTO q_form (question,answer) VALUES ('$question','$answer');";    
    mysqli_query($conn,$insert);
    header("Location: ../admin.php?signup=success");
 }
```

the admin.php code is where textarea is embedded and is where the data is fed into the database.

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Admin</title>
        <style>
            body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100vh;
                background: white;
            }
    
            .admin-body {
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                position: absolute;
            }
    
            .admin-body input {
                width: 96%;
                padding: 5px;
                margin-bottom: 5%;
            }
    
            .admin-body textarea {
                padding: 5px;
            }
    
            .submit input {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="admin-body">
            <form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="question">            
                <textarea name="answer" id="textarea" cols="50" rows="20"></textarea>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
    
            </form>
        </div>    
        
    </body>
    
    </html>```
````

connect.php connects the html pages with the database**

````
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db_connect');
?>```
````

Comment: I don't have time to read through your question at this moment, but I can tell you that `@include 'includes/connect.php';` is generally not a good practice. First, that is your database connection which I would assume is required, and not optional, so a `require` would probably better describe that. Second, and more important, you are suppressing any errors using the `@` operator and don't appear to be testing anything later. Leaking database credentials is a reason to use `@` but I'd recommend doing it at the `mysqli_connect` level instead.

Comment: Thanks Chris,that observation is helpfull to.

Comment: You have not shown what the data looks like.  Presumably you are showing it in the textarea.